# JQ - format JSON array appending values to a specific a value

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am trying to get this:

```
[   
    ["John Black",[ 
        ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",27], 
        ["Ut tempus lectus ut mi.",23]
    ]],
    ["Peter Pan",[ 
        ["Quisque pulvinar odio.",22],
        ["Nec ut lorem quis interdum elit.",32]
    ]],
    ["Gary Halbert",[ 
        ["Placerat aliquam.",17]
    ]],
    ["Richard Gere",[ 
        ["Porttitor commodo fermentum.",28]
    ]]
]
```

Till now, this is what I got:

```
export A=$(cat <<'EOL'
[
["John Black",["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",27]],
["Peter Pan",["Quisque pulvinar odio.",22]],
["John Black",["Ut tempus lectus ut mi.",23]],
["Gary Halbert",["Placerat aliquam.",17]],
["Peter Pan",["Nec ut lorem quis interdum elit.",32]],
["Richard Gere",["Porttitor commodo fermentum.",28]]
]
EOL
)
echo "$A" | jq 'map({(.[0]): .[1]}) | add'
```

Resulting this:

```
{
  "John Black": [
    "Ut tempus lectus ut mi.",
    23
  ],
  "Peter Pan": [
    "Nec ut lorem quis interdum elit.",
    32
  ],
  "Gary Halbert": [
    "Placerat aliquam.",
    17
  ],
  "Richard Gere": [
    "Porttitor commodo fermentum.",
    28
  ]
}
```

I am using jq-1.5.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Aside: `export` is utterly unneeded here; it's using a limited resource unnecessarily (environment variables are stored in the same space used for the argument vector, so when you export a shell variable you're decreasing your maximum command-line length for all subprocesses of that shell).

Comment: Man, where did you learn that? If that was a book, please, I want that too...

Comment: @Roger: See http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an appropriate use case for a reducer. Most of the below is related not to joining items under shared keys, but to getting them into the desired nested-list form:

```
jq -n '[
  inputs |
  reduce .[] as $item ({}; .[$item[0]] += [$item[1]]) |
  to_entries |
  .[] |
  [.key, .value]
]' <<<"$A"
```

...yields as output (edited only for compactness with regard to whitespace):

```
[
  ["John Black", [["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", 27], ["Ut tempus lectus ut mi.",23]]],
  ["Peter Pan", [["Quisque pulvinar odio.",22], ["Nec ut lorem quis interdum elit.", 32]]],
  ["Gary Halbert", [["Placerat aliquam.", 17]]],
  ["Richard Gere", [["Porttitor commodo fermentum.", 28]]]
]
```

Comment: If there is a book or a course about this, I want to know!

Comment: @Roger: You won't find such advanced techniques in the [tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/), but the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) covers everything - albeit in a condensed form that may not make the possibilities obvious. The manual does have examples, however, and there's also an [online playground](https://jqplay.org/). Finally, there are plenty of excellent answers on SO already (this one definitely qualifies).

Answer (score 0):

the Couchdb engine is append only, it means that each document will append into a file manager by Couchdb, and each file is related to a db.

to use properly think how to avoid updates in the same document, remember all revisions will be storage.

my suggestion for each document.

```js
{
  "name": "John Black",
  "entries": [
    {
      "test": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
      "value": 27
    }, 
    {
       "text": "Ut tempus lectus ut mi.",
       "value": 23
    }
  ],
  "type": "user"
}
```

Comment: So, with CouchDB, if I need to add other quotes to an author I will have to read the JSON object/array, make the addition and overwrite the entire document?

Comment: yes and this will generate a revision, which is a copy of the document.

Comment: Did a prior rev of the question reference CouchDB? (As the current version asks only about jq, I'm curious to see this here).

Comment: The question was too large so I edited it. As far as I could see, I did not had too much to gain, in my case, working with CouchDB. Indeed, I decided it would be quicker to save the JSON array into a gunziped text file and read it back JQ to further editions.